# Calendar as iframe jump to other area when applied scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, calendar

Before applied scrollable container, the calendar works fine.

[Works calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EpLt.png)

After i applied a scrollable container as code:

```
<style>
 #container { 
   overflow:auto;
   position:relative; 
   height:100%; 
   } 
 </style>
```

and the calendar will jump to other areas. Calendar's position set to 'Absolute', I tried to set as 'Fixed' but only work for chrome and IE 11. Our compatibility is IE 5.

[Not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaueV.png)

I tried many another way also can't. seek help!